# EmbedsMany + loopback + mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

How to set '`embedsMany`' relation for nested key in loopback.  for I have the following schema for mongoDB.....

```
"profile":{
   "A":{
        "key1":[{},{}],
        "key2":[{},{}]
       }
}

key1 ---> is a separate model
key2 ----> is separate model
```

For the above schema how can i set the relations. For the above schema i can set "`embedsMany`" realtions, but how can i set for nested key?. Please share ur idea. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Take a look at official documentation: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Embedded-models-and-relations.html